# Problem assigning action in BGE

Tags: animation, game-engine, logic-bricks

I created an action, "run", in the animation editor.

To create the animation, I moved the bones in pose mode and used *automatic keyframes*, so, for each movement of the bones, it creates a new frame.

I don't know if I forgot something, but with the animation complete, I added a keyboard sensor in the *Game Logic Editor* and set the key to <kbd>W</kbd>.

I then added an *And* controller and the action "run". I used the following settings:

- Action playback type to *loop stop*
- *start frame* `1`
- *End frame* `30`
- *blending* `3`

I then connected the logic bricks. What I don't get is that when I press <kbd>P</kbd> and <kbd>W</kbd>, the character doesn't execute the animation.

I don't know what to do; I have read many pages; I have seen many tutorials, but I don't get how to do this part.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Could you add your .blend?

Comment: Make sure you have the character parented to the armature with armature deform. I've had problems with the game engine recognizing just the armature modifier without parenting.

Comment: You probably need to arrange the Layers in each Action property. For example: Layer0 standing Layer1 walking Layer2 running etc. Hope this helped! I ran into the same problem as you and this solved it for me.

Answer (score 3):

I had met this problem.   And googled about this matter, but nothing helpful.
Eventually and suddenly when I applied the "subdivision surface" modifier to the rigid bodies (Remember: not the "armatures") surprisingly it done.
So to fix this first keep in mind to be sure to apply any Modifiers relate to the rigid bodies then look after other specifics in the (game logic bricks) if needed some works.
I added this information to my mind and hope to help others.. Thank you.

Comment: Just to make this *super* clear, it's the Mirror modifier that really messes the stuff up.